# Send action from ajax response with ember

Tags: jquery, ember.js

I'm new to ember & I try to send action to some route in my app,
But I want to send the action from AJAX response because I also need the inserted id from the server
So I try to do:

```
$.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    url: "in",
    data: datajson,
    success: function (result) {
        data.id = result.id;
        self.sendAction('action', data);
    }
});
```

`self` is a global variable that I assign to it the value of `this` of the component.

Now its not working, nothing sent to the router
But when I put the `sendAction` out of the ajax success function
The function in the "father" route is trigerred

**EDIT1:**

The templates are:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="in/income">
    {{create-in classes=model action="addIn"}}
</script>
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="in/expend">
    {{create-in classes=model action="addIn"}}
</script>
```

The component js code:

```
App.CreateInComponent = Ember.Component.extend({
    classNames: ['fixed'],
    sum:null,
    cllass: null,
    d:null,
    actions: {
        create: function (classes) {
            var classe = this.get('cllass');
            var sum = this.get('sum');
            des = classes.filterBy('id', classe)[0].des;
            self = this;
            data = {sum: sum, class: classe, date: this.get('d')};
            var dataJSON = JSON.stringify(data);
            data.des = des;
            $.ajax({
                method: "POST",
                url: "in",
                data: dataJSON,
                success: function (result) {
                    data.id = result.id;
                    this.sendAction('action', data);
                }
            });

         }
    }
});
```

So what I can do?
(I use Ember 1.10)

**EDIT2:**

I thought on a solution, my solution is to send the action to the router and there make ajax call to the server and then insert the to model the data
My code in the router handler:

```
addIn: function (dataJSON) {
    self = this;
    $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        url: "in",
        data: dataJSON,
        success: function (result) {
            data.id = result.id;
            self.get('model').pushObject(Ember.Object.create(data));
        }
    });
}
```

But I get this error in the console:

> (index):265 Uncaught TypeError: self.get(...) is not a function

I try to search and i found that I need to add `.toArray` function after the get method, but its dosent work either

What to do?

Comment: Can you show template and show how do you add component to template?

Comment: @MirzaMemic I edit my question, please look at the both edits, thanks.

Comment: Please also include component JS code. thanks

Comment: Are you serious about `self` being global? If yes, why, and it makes sense that its not breaking. If not, in your EDIT2 is a `var` before the `self` missing. And what are you *really* trying to achieve? Are you using 'ember-data'? Have you considered using a current ember version?

Comment: @MirzaMemic I edit and added the component code

Comment: @Lux First I don't use current version of ember because I just pratice for a project that constructed on 1.10, second I declare `self` as a global variable because I need access to it from the ajax `success` function, I'm not using Ember-Data , I just do simple ajax requests to the server to get data, and I store it in the model, What I trying to achieve is to add the data that the user insert to a table in the page, but I also need the inserted id from the server

Comment: @NatiVaknin still it doesn't need to be global if its in the surrounding [closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures).

Comment: @Lux I have tried this before and it's not worked for me, now I try and its work, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ok , someone at work helped me, the solution is for the second problem, mean the solution that I suggested
The reason that I get this error its because the model sit on the controller, so its can't be found on the route

the solution is to do like that:

```
self.get('controller.model').pushObject(Ember.Object.create(data));
```